# Braintree and submitted for settlement

Tags: braintree

If I understand correctly, when a transaction is created and "submitted for settlement", it can still fail.

Are we supposed to poll the server to know when it moved out of the "submitted for settlement" status ?

Comment: I have a hard time thinking of a scenario 
where 'submit for settlement' would fail. I suppose if a customer canceled 
their account between authorization and the attempt to capture, but I believe this would be an error that Braintree would receive on their end.

Comment: The documentation in braintree suggests not to ship goods before the transaction is settled.

Comment: This isn't really a technical question, and it may depend on your specific processor. I recommend reaching out to Braintree support for a more complete answer: https://www.braintreepayments.com/contact

Comment: I just sent them a mail.

Comment: Hello @Leo did you figure out the solution ?

Comment: @PunitaOjha Unfortunately I did not get a reply I found valuable. So I am going to test the other solution I am aware of: https://firebase.google.com/docs/use-cases/payments